# Discord Prediction Bot

Tags: python, button, discord.py

I'm trying to create a bot that my friends and I can do predictions through for the upcoming Soccer World Championship.
Now I want this bot to be able to ask the result of each match as a question, with a button for answer.
Creating one question works perfectly, but then moving on to the next question is what I have issues with.

I found the following online:

"Each message is a different view, but you don't need to program each view. You can create a class that inherits from discord.ui.button where it takes a team name as a string, then pass that button (plus another for the 2nd team) to a class that inherits from discord.ui.View"

I'm a beginner when it comes to python and I have no clue how I actually do this. Any tips?

What I want:

- Message 1: "Team A vs Team B"
- Button 1: Team A
- Button 2: Team B
- Message 2: "Team C vs Team C"
- Button 1: Team C
- Button 2: Team D

The code I currently already have:

```py
class WorldsGeneral(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, *, timeout=10):
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Groups", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def Finals(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.send_message()
# The messages for predictions would have to be send by pressing this button ^

    @discord.ui.button(label="Standings")
    async def Standings(
        self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button
    ):
        await interaction.response.send_message()


@bot.command(aliases=["poule", "predictions])
async def worlds(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        colour=0x0433f3,
        title=":trophy: Worlds Poule 2022 :trophy:",
    )
    embed.set_image(
        url=f"https://thumbs.gfycat.com/AccomplishedAdorableClumber-size_restricted.gif"
    )

    view = WorldsGeneral()
    msg = await ctx.send(
        ":construction: Major Work In Progress :construction:", view=view
    )
    view.orig_mes = msg
```

Comment: Is the `worlds` command used for moving onto the next question?

Comment: No, that's a larger general command. The ```groups``` button is supposed to start the predictions after which every press of a button moves the user on to the next match.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with your `worlds` command: there's a missing quotation at the very top. Here's how the fixed code should look:

```
@bot.command(aliases=["poule", "predictions"]) # Missing quotation right here
async def worlds(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        colour=0x0433f3,
        title=":trophy: Worlds Poule 2022 :trophy:",
    )
    embed.set_image(
        url=f"https://thumbs.gfycat.com/AccomplishedAdorableClumber-size_restricted.gif"
    )

    view = WorldsGeneral()
    msg = await ctx.send(
        ":construction: Major Work In Progress :construction:", view=view
    )
    view.orig_mes = msg
```

Comment: Thanks, but afraid that was just a copy+paste error. Left some other irrelevant aliases (and buttons) out of the question :P